# Cors issue with node js and React Js

Tags: node.js, cors

I have tried all solutions, but doesn't work, and i don't have any idea how i can do to solve this problem

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.bolaosolidario.com.br/afiliado/' from origin 'https://app.bolaosolidario.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to reinstall cors, change my nginx configuration, change my cors in my api configuration, but doesn't work. The cors issue, occurs after a while that the user already has the site open, and i don't know what can cause this, my server configuration:

```js
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routers')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
require('./database')
/*const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'device-remember-token', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Origin', 'Accept', ' Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'],
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};*/

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(routes)
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

I tried with two ways, i tried to use de cors options and a tried to use just the cors, but both configurations give me the same error.

my nginx configuration

```nginx
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.bolaosolidario.com.br;
    root /home/forge/api.bolaosolidario.com.br/dist;
    
     # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/api.bolaosolidario.com.br/1377016/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/api.bolaosolidario.com.br/1377016/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type";
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/api.bolaosolidario.com.br/server/*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # Port number of node http server
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE, UPDATE';
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/api.bolaosolidario.com.br-error.log error;



}
```

And i have tried to use without the cors, but return the same error, in different routers.

Comment: You should not be setting CORS headers in `proxy_set_header`. Those are passed _to_ the upstream service but CORS headers should only be in the response

Comment: But i tried without and return the same error,  thanks for help me!

Comment: Just general advice and not an answer

Comment: were you able to solve the issue? I don't see any issue in your node js code.  

Were you able to make a successful  API call to your endpoint with postman?  If yes, then it means you have issue with your nodejs cors config. IF NO,  it can be because of Nginx reverse proxy setup that the client not able to connect to the nodejs server through nginx. 
Postman doesn't block CORS, but the browser does.

Comment: these options don't solved my problem, i've been think, my problem have start after i install the ssl,  should be a problem with the ssl

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but why are you always set 'Connection' header to 'Upgrade'?

Comment: It's just a config i found the internet, i don't understand soo much of the nginx

Answer (score -1):

to use CORS, you can use the express direct method like this :

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, authorization');
    next();
});
```

It works for me, I think it could solve your problem. Nginx doesn't need any particular configuration to work with CORS, the basic one or the one generated by certbot works correctly

Comment: The [cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) OP is already using does all this and better